# Enabling HTTP/2 on Azure

Tags: azure, http2

My Azure hosted Web Site has the following configuration (see image).

[image]

So I believe I have enabled HTTP/2.

However, when I access it from Edge/Chrome and in the Development options choose "Report".  I get (see image):

[image]

**IGNORE** the "localhost" bit.  I took the screen capture from my local copy, but I get the same when I run the report on my Azure version of the site.

Why is it saying http/1.1?

Comment: can you do a curl -I <your site> and paste the result in here?

Answer (score 0):

Double check in the resource explorer if http2enabled is set to true. Go to:

Subscription > Resource Group > your site name > Providers > Microsoft.Web > sites > your site name > config > web

[image]

[image]

then select PUT

[image]

source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-http-2-support-in-azure-app-service/

Comment: My Azure looks nothing like the above.  I tried adding "httpEnabled" : true to my appsettings.json, but this had no effect.

Comment: One thing.  Does the site have to be httpS to support http/2?

Comment: yes, should be https. Please try a curl -I <your site>

Comment: ahh ok, that's probably why then.  I can't check httpS for a while.